# How to transfer a CCSprite from one parent to another?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, cclayer

I have a `CCSprite` called `sprite` that is a child of a `CCLayer` called `movingLayer` that is itself a child of the current `CCLayer` running my game logic, so it is `self` in this case.  `movingLayer` is moving back and forth across the screen in a repeat forever action and `sprite` is riding along on it.  I want to get `sprite` to "get off" of `movingLayer` and "get on" to `self` where it can do some actions of its own.

When I try to do this, I need to tell `movingLayer` to remove `sprite` and `self` to add `sprite.`  This is what I did...

```
- (void)attack:(id)sender
{
    [sprite stopAllActions];
    [movingLayer removeChild:sprite cleanup:YES];
    [self addChild:sprite z:1];
    CGFloat distance = ccpDistance(sprite.position, ccp(sprite.position.x, -sprite.contentSize.height/2));
    id goDown = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:distance/moveDuration position:ccp(sprite.position.x, -sprite.contentSize.height/2)];
    id repeatDown = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0 position:ccp(sprite.position.x, sprite.contentSize.height/2+self.contentSize.height)], [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:moveDuration position:ccp(sprite.position.x, -sprite.contentSize.height/2)], nil]];
    id attackAction = [CCSequence actions:goDown, repeatDown, nil];
    [sprite runAction:attackAction];
}
```

I think `stopAllActions` is redundant, but that's not the problem.  If I remove `sprite` from `movingLayer` before adding it to `self` I crash for accessing a zombie, and if I try to add it to `self` first, I crash for trying to add something already added.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried setting cleanup to NO?

Alternatively, try to retain sprite before you remove it from movingLayer, then release it when you're done with it:

```
[sprite retain];
[movingLayer removeChild:sprite cleanup:YES];
[self addChild:sprite z:1];
[sprite release];
```